# How to mock a connectivityManager without mock context in espresso

Tags: mockito, android-espresso

I'm writing espresso test which requires wifi connection, just need to get connectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered() return false in emulator. I think mock a connectivityManager is a way, but I cannot mock the application context in my test, is there any other way to implement it?